# Package and Installation via app exchange

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, package-install

We want to create connected app. Connected app contains Callback url and Canvas App URL.

Can we package this to create and publish app on app exchange? Once this package is installed onto different organization from appexchange, can that org update the callback url? In our case the prospective client will have their own url for callback and canvas which is custom url.

(How) can this be done ?

Comment: Why do you want to package the connected app then? Just create a connected app on client side, set the url and use those secrets to do whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry I am new to sf. Dont have much understanding. Thanks for advise .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subscriber org cannot update the callback and Canvas URL once packaged .

In this case its preferred to have administration instructions for the org administrator to create the connected app while you can package other code .Also you can always read the canvas app name from the custom setting .

Comment: Is there alternative to creating connected apps in this scenarios?

Comment: The other option is to maintain a common url and in the first canvas signed  request the vf page will send the callback url from custom setting and then you can redirect to proper url .Also note that start URL can be contacted configured

Comment: Can we add "variable" custom settings added to both canvas and callback url?